# My code is giving NoSuchElementException after first round of input loop at any scanner after first iteration

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I run my code in the first iteration of the loop, it normally reads the values for that element and stores in arraylist. But after that any scanner is when I reach any scanner, it isn't giving me any chance to enter the variable and gives NoSuchElementException

What I expected was something like this

```
Enter the number of shapes: 3
Enter 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle, 3 for Square: 1 
Enter Radius : 1
The area is 3.14 and the perimeter is 6.28
Enter 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle, 3 for Square: 2 Enter Length and Breadth: 5 4
The area is 20 and the perimeter is 18
Enter 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle, 3 for Square: 3 Enter Side: 2
The area is 4 and the perimeter is 8
Enter the threshold value: 15
The shapes are Rectangle(5,4)
```

The other classes rectangle and square are similar to circle

```
class Circle
{
    int radius;

    public void readAttributes() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Radius: ");
        radius = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
    }

    public double calculateArea() {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
    
    public double calculatePerimeter() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    public void displayAttributes()
    {
        System.out.print("Circle("+this.radius+") ");
    }
   
}
```

```
public class Q7 {
    private static final DecimalFormat decfor = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of shapes: ");
        int numshapes = scanner.nextInt();
        int choice=0;
        List<Object> shapes=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numshapes; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle, 3 for Square: ");
            //Second iteration there is NoSuchElementException
            choice=scanner.nextInt();
            switch (choice) 
            {
                case 1:
                Circle circle = new Circle();
                circle.readAttributes();
                System.out.println("The area is "+decfor.format(circle.calculateArea())+" and the perimeter is "+decfor.format(circle.calculatePerimeter()));
                shapes.add(circle);
                break;

                case 2:
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                rectangle.readAttributes();
                rectangle.displayAreaAndPerimeter();
                shapes.add(rectangle);
                break;

                case 3:
                Square square = new Square();
                square.readAttributes();
                square.displayAreaAndPerimeter();
                shapes.add(square);
                break;

                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice! Try Again.");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the threshold value: ");
        //If it reaches here also it gives NoSuchElementException
        int threshold=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("The shapes are ");
        for(Object shape:shapes){
            if (shape instanceof Circle) {
                Circle circle=(Circle) shape;

                if((circle.calculateArea())>threshold)
                    circle.displayAttributes();
            }
            else if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
                Rectangle rectangle=(Rectangle) shape;

                if((rectangle.calculateArea())>threshold)
                    rectangle.displayAttributes();
            }
            else if (shape instanceof Square) {
                Square square=(Square) shape;

                if((square.calculateArea())>threshold)
                    square.displayAttributes();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because closing the scanner also closes `System.in`, meaning that you can’t read from it again. You should create the scanner once, and pass it to other methods that need it.